# After a while, Ubuntu slows down tremendously

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

So, I'm going to list my specs first.

1. Ryzen 3 3200g
2. XPG Hunter 8 GB DDR4-2666 MHz (at 2880 MHz. Only one running in a single channel.)
3. Asus Prime A320M-K
4. 1 TB 2.5" HDD

So my suspicion is that it is the single stick of RAM, as the Ryzen 3 3200g likes its RAM.

But, in some post, I can't link it, because I can't find it again, almost identical specs except he had a dual-channel, but noted that he also had to restart his PC occasionally because it slowed down, just like my case. I can't be restarting my PC mid-class. But as well I have read other peoples post, that it is some GPU issue with Linux and a Vega 8.

**EDIT**: I am currently checking my `syslogs`. Also, I will keep a free terminal open at all times, so when it freezes, I can type free and upload.

**MORE EDIT**: Here is a screenshot of the things you requested. I made my own swap file. It is 10 GB in total size. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NNER.jpg Oh, and my RAM was at 2880 MHz but I lowered it to stock and same results. No, my CPU is not overclocked, A320 chip-sets can't overclock.

Comment: If you think it's RAM, then [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1297500/edit) to include the complete output of `free` during regular use...and then again during a slowdown. Compare the two. Then you will *know* if it is RAM or not.

Comment: If you think that it's a GPU issue, start looking in /var/log/syslog for evidence.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Is your CPU or RAM overclocked?